# Android 6.0 keystore ClassCast Exception

Tags: java, android, cryptography, android-6.0-marshmallow, java-security

I'm using the [Qlassified library](https://github.com/Q42/Qlassified-Android) and I'm getting the following exception being thrown on android 6.0 and 6.0.1:
`java.lang.ClassCastException: android.security.keystore.AndroidKeyStoreECPublicKey cannot be cast to java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey`

Specifically, this happens when the data is being encrypted inside of this code block:

```
final KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry privateKeyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) keyStoreInstance.getEntry(alias, null);

final RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) privateKeyEntry.getCertificate().getPublicKey(); // error

byte[] dataBytes = input.getBytes(CHARSET);
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM, ANDROID_MODE);
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
return Base64.encodeToString(cipher.doFinal(dataBytes), BASE64_MODE);
```

any thoughts?

Comment: Use a certificate with an RSA public key?

Answer (score 1):

This comes from the generation of keys stored on keystore. You were using an EC algorithm. You must specify RSA algorithm like this:

```
KeyPairGenerator generator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance(KeyProperties.KEY_ALGORITHM_RSA, "AndroidKeyStore");
                    generator.initialize(params);
```

I had the same problem and this solved it.